# Setup Node.js HTTPS to work with HAPROXY

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, haproxy, requestjs

I'm trying to make my nodejs app to communicate with HAPROXY via https. The idea is that nodejs sends message to haproxy via https, haproxy routes message forward.

I used request.js library and all worked fine, but now I need to perform this task without any libraries. The scenario is following. If environment variable is 1, I should use HTTP, in other cases -HTTPS. The problem is that when I use https and haproxy, I get "Socket hangup error", but everything works fine with request.js. Here is my code.

```
const protocol = process.env.NODE_ENV === 1 ? require('http') : require('https');
```

then I configure HTTPS

```
this.api = url.parse(app.get('API_HAPROXY'));
this.options = {
    port: this.api.port,
    hostname: this.api.hostname,
    path: '/api/report',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    requestCert: true,
    agent: false
};
```

Because I don't want to use ca to validate ssh keys I use `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0`

```
reportData(json) {
    const req = protocol.request(this.options, (res) => {
        res.on('error', (err) => {
            this.logger.error(`Failed to report ${err.message}`)
        })
    });
    req.write(JSON.stringify(json));
    req.end();
    req.on('error', (err) => {
        this.logger.error(`Failed to report ${err.message}`);
    });
}
```

In this case I get socket hangup error while using HTTPS

Here is my request configuration

```
request({
    uri: `${this.api}/api/report`,
    method: 'POST',
    json,
}, (err, response) => {
    if (err || response.statusCode !== 200) {
        this.logger.error(`Failed to report : ${err ? err.message : response.statusCode}`);
    } else {
        this.logger.info(`Report was sent`);
    }
});
```

Comment: Does the proxy url contain a port?

Comment: `process.env.NODE_ENV === 1` I feel like env values are strings so this will be false all the time

Comment: Yes. It contains. It works with request. The problem is not in environment, as it uses https, I've checked it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed by adding content-length header to the options.headers.

```
this.api = url.parse(app.get('API_HAPROXY')); this.options = { 
port: this.api.port,
 hostname: this.api.hostname, 
path: '/api/report', 
method: 'POST', 
headers: { 
 "Content-Type": "application/json",
"Content-Length: <calculated length of the object you want to send in bytes >
}, 
rejectUnauthorized: false, 
requestCert: true,
agent: false
 };
```